# How can I make the file path, in order to find the correct files on any PC?

Tags: c#

I am making a program where I need 24 pictures and a text file. I have all the files on my computer, and I easily fetch them with this code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/myUser/Documents/myFolder/myPicture.jpg");
```

The problem is that this path is unique for my PC, not many have my username, if you have windows in a different languague if won't work either, and you would have to save the folder containing the program in documents.

What I need is in some way make the program search after the image files in the same folder where the program is, regardless where it is stored on the PC like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("/myFolder/myPicture.jpg");
```

I think this is pretty basic, adding a picture to your program, in order to transfer it to other PCs, but I have not found the solution anywhere.

Seems like the problem is solved, is there any way to set it to solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
string picPath = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "mypicture.jpg");
```

picPath is the same path as "your app directory" + "mypicure.jpg"

Comment: thank you so much. This was both very effective and worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Just omit the first /

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("myFolder/myPicture.jpg");
```

you can also do

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/myFolder/myPicture.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath`.

It is documented here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx